# Is there a way to execute XSS without greater than sign ( > )?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xss

So I am writing a function in javascript that should strip potentially harmful code to protect from DOM based XSS. But now that I figured some solution and started testing it I came to realization that I don't know something important that can help me simplify my code. So my question is, is there a way to execute XSS without closing "greater than" sign ( > ) ?

Comment: Yes... all depends on how it is injected.

Comment: Please search OWASP for XSS prevention. Filtering (>) is without a doubt not enough to prevent XSS.

Comment: @user120242 I know it is not enough and that is not my case. I was just wondering if there is a way to execute XSS without placing > anywhere. So to be more detailed, just imagine that you have something like this: <img src=x onerror=confirm("BOOM") but there is no closing tag ( > ). My guess is that browser will close it somehow without having to close it personally but I am not really sure.

Comment: @user120242 so it seems it's a good idea to escape this `<` instead of `>`.